# SQL Subquery issue - Invalid object name

Tags: sql, t-sql, nested, subquery, syntax-error

I have prepared the below "subquery" code.  Error message: "Invalid object name 'group1-2'" is shown.  May I know how to fix the issue.

```
select
  CASE
    WHEN reference_s = 'R1' THEN
      (select sum(DATEDIFF(second, datetime2_s,datetime6_s) ) from group1_2)
    WHEN reference_s = 'R2' THEN
      (select sum(DATEDIFF(second, datetime3_s,datetime6_s) ) from group1_2)
  END
  / (CAST(count(*) AS float)*60)
from
(
  select * from
  (
    select
      id,
      min(reference) as reference_s, min(datetime2) as datetime2_s,
      min(datetime3) as datetime3_s, max(datetime6) as datetime6_s,
      count(*) as type_s, sum(size) as size_s
    from dbo.testing
    group by id
  ) group1
  where type_s=2 and cntr_size_s=44
  UNION
  select * from
  (
    select
      id,
      min(reference) as reference_s, min(datetime2) as datetime2_s,
      min(datetime3) as datetime3_s, max(datetime6) as datetime6_s,
      count(*) as type_s, sum(size) as size_s
    from dbo.testing
    group by id
  ) group2
  where type_s=1
) group1_2
where datetime6_s IS NOT null
and datetime6_s >= '2023-03-01 00:00'
and datetime6_s <= '2023-03-30 23:59'
```

Comment: No idea; because you have not provided the complete error message. Edit you question with the complete message - copy and paste as text - don't use an image. There is an [Edit] link beneath the tags - use that.

Comment: instead of this: `datetime6_s >= '2023-03-01 00:00' AND datetime6_s <= '2023-03-30 23:59'`  use this: `datetime6_s >= '20230301' AND datetime6_s < '20230331' `  "datetime" values are more precise than 1 minute - but perhaps you also meant `datetime6_s >= '20230301' AND datetime6_s < '20230401' `  (ALL of March)

Comment: It might also be a good idea to generate a table var and insert some dummy test data into it so that someone can paste this right into their SSMS and debug it.

Comment: Please see my answer for an explanation. You are getting the error, because you nee a `WITH` clause in order to access the data set `group1_2` multiple times. Try to fix the other errors, too. If you don't get this working, create a new request with the amended query describing what the query is supposed to do exactly. Add sample data and the expected result then, so we see what you are after. Don't change this request, because it is properly asked and answered. Make a new request with the new question, if you get stuck with your new query.

Comment: Side notes: `type_s` is a strange name for a count. `where datetime6_s is not null` is superfluous. And I too would write the date range condition as Pauls suggests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `FROM` clause you have a subquery the result of which you call `group1_2`. In your `SELECT` clause you have subqueries selecting from this. This is not allowed in SQL, because in the `SELECT` clause you look at a single row from the table (or an aggregated row of it). The `SELECT` clause does not know the whole table. If you want to define such an ad-hoc view that you can access multiple times in your query, you must make this a CTE (aka `WITH` clause).

But there are more flaws in your query:

- You have `from (...) group1 where ... cntr_size_s = 44`, but you don't select any `cntr_size_s` in `group1`.
- You have `from (...) group2 where ... cntr_size_s = 44`, but you don't select any `cntr_size_s` in `group2`.
- You have `select case when reference_s = 'R1' ...end ... / cast(count(*) ...)`. So you access a column from `group1_2` and an aggregation result. But there is no `GROUP BY reference_s`, which would give you an aggregation result per `reference_s`. So how could the data you are accessing here be aggregated to a single row (`COUNT(*)`) and not aggregated (`reference_s`) at the same time? This is not possible. `GROUP BY reference_s` could solve this syntactically, but I don't know whether this is the solution you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Subquery which you used from the derived table is not allowed in SELECT part.
Apart from that few more logical issues are there in your query
If you want your query to run without any issue then try below

```
select
  CASE
    WHEN reference_s = 'R1' THEN
      sum(DATEDIFF(second, datetime2_s,datetime6_s))
    WHEN reference_s = 'R2' THEN
      sum(DATEDIFF(second, datetime3_s,datetime6_s) )
  END
  / (CAST(count(*) AS float)*60)
from
(
  select * from
  (
    select
      id,
      min(reference) as reference_s, min(datetime2) as datetime2_s,
      min(datetime3) as datetime3_s, max(datetime6) as datetime6_s,
      count(*) as type_s, sum(size) as size_s
    from dbo.testing
    group by id
  ) group1
  where type_s=2 and cntr_size_s=44
  UNION
  select * from
  (
    select
      id,
      min(reference) as reference_s, min(datetime2) as datetime2_s,
      min(datetime3) as datetime3_s, max(datetime6) as datetime6_s,
      count(*) as type_s, sum(size) as size_s
    from dbo.testing
    group by id
  ) group2
  where type_s=1
) group1_2
where datetime6_s IS NOT null
and datetime6_s >= '2023-03-01 00:00'
and datetime6_s <= '2023-03-30 23:59'
GROUP BY id,reference_s
```

Comment: Thanks.   I have tried your amended code and no issue is found.  However I can not get the result I wanted.  In fact, I have prepared the sql as below before...
sum(
CASE WHEN reference_s = 'R1' THEN DATEDIFF(second, datetime2_s,datetime6_s) 
  WHEN reference_s='R2' THEN DATEDIFF(second, datetime3_s,datetime6_s)
END)  /(CAST(count(*)  AS float)*60)   ....
However I don't want to use nested aggregate function. So I have tried to use subquery.

Comment: @San: As I have mentioned in the request comments: You asked about the error "Invalid object name 'group1-2'", and this has been answered. I even pointed out other flaws in your query. With this knowledge you can go on and work on your query. It is rather obvious that you don't want to use the above query, as aggregating by id means not aggregating at all. So think about what you want to achieve and amend your query. If you get stuck, open a new request inclding sample data and expected result.